# How would I go about measuring an analog signal on my arduino mega that has both positive and negative voltages

Tags: arduino-mega, analogread, voltage-level, voltage, analogreadresolution

I have a signal that fluctuates between -70mV and 50mV. How would I get the arduino to read this.. Ultimately I am trying to graph the data in real time so it looks like this.

[image: Positive/Negative voltage]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8zIE.jpg

Comment: i don't think an arduino has much sensitivity (precision) between such close values. I would use an op amp to amplify it to ~0-5v, after it went through a voltage sum circuit, a dual op amp like the 358 will  let you do both with one chip.

Answer (score 1):

You need to amplify your signal and add 2.5V as a "virtual ground" for the amplification. This gets a little tricky, since you need a low-impedance V<sub>CC</sub>/2 source to feed the amplifier as a virtual ground.  This would require a unity-gain buffer fed from a voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJUM1h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now you use that to feed the amplifier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftgW1D.png)</sup>

The gain is set by 1+(RF/RG), or 11 in this case, giving you -0.77V to +0.55V.

There is a simpler option, though. (There is another intermediate option but the editor lost it and I can't be bothered to spend the time recreating it).

This method does come at a cost, though: it inverts the signal. The -0.07 becomes 0.07 and the 0.05 becomes -0.05, and multiplied by the gain and added to the offset:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiElkY.png)</sup>

Here you get a transformation from -0.07V - +0.05V to +0.7V - -0.5V.  That means that *in software* you then have to invert the value (simply subtract it from 0 after removing the DC offset).

You're basically shifting some of the complexity out of the circuitry and into the software.

Personally I use the inverting amplifier (the last circuit) because the virtual ground current is near zero, so you don't need a low impedance V<sub>CC</sub>/2 voltage source. It's also easier to create more sensible gains (like 10x) than the non-inverting amplifier, which always has 1 added to the gain.

Comment: Your second circuit doesn't have a well defined DC working point.

Comment: Quite possibly not. I was having a nightmare of a time with the editor. It kept wiping stuff out and crashing and deleting circuits.

Comment: @EdgarBonet The op-amp was upside down in the non-inverting second stage... oops...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try at this: if your voltage source doesn't mind sinking
something like 150 µA, you could try something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffsipE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should map the input range [−70 mV, +50 mV] to
[0.04 V, 4.06 V].